# How to convert Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Document into a Byte Array?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to create a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Document and convert that into a Byte Array without saving it into the file system as this code will on Azure Function.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Office (or in your case at least Word) installed on the machine where you want to use the Interop library. So that is a clear: No, you cannot do this with Azure Functions as you cannot install software like that there.

See also here for requirements: https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/c-sharp-microsoft-office-interop-word-automation

Possible workaround might be to use something like this OpenXML SDK: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK